# HTML 5 Canvas Cropping Results In Bad Quality

Tags: html, canvas

I've made a quick sample at http://yc.sg/fantaspic/compare.html. It's ugly and just there for the functions. It uses FileAPIs, nothing to sent to the server side so feel free to try using any photo :P. Ok, to use it, just browse, choose a photo and click ok, then crop away.

The image at the bottom left is redrawn using HTML 5 canvas (with the original image as source), while the one at the bottom right is just a div with the original image being moved around. The canvas image always results in a lower quality, although it is just a simple crop.

You can view source and see how it works, but the main method for cropping is this:

```
function preview(img, selection) {
        var scaleX = previewWidth / selection.width; 
        var scaleY = previewHeight / selection.height; 

        $('#cropped-image').css({ 
            width: Math.round(scaleX * truew) + 'px', 
            height: Math.round(scaleY * trueh) + 'px',
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px', 
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px' 
        });

        selx1 = selection.x1;
        sely1 = selection.y1;
        selx2 = selection.x2;
        sely2 = selection.y2;
        selw = selection.width;
        selh = selection.height;

        var canvas = $("#preview")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(img, selx1, sely1, selw, selh, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a difference. OSX, Opera

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 canvas elements have **width** and **height** property attached to them which sets up the viewport of the canvas. Both of those properties are **not** the same as their css counterparts.

Consider a regular bitmap image. The size of the image is fixed and cannot be changed in the browser. However, the css width and height properties allow you to scale and distort the image. Sometimes that ain't pretty because browsers tend to use simple resizing algorithms.

It's the same with your canvas. The viewport you set (or the default one) is used to determine where the pixels are drawn. Thus a bitmap is created which **afterwards** gets resized by css.

In your case the canvas image is slightly upscaled, because your css values (320, 320) differ from the default viewport values (300,300). Just try to set up your viewport in advance and all should look fine.

```
$(function () {
  var $preview = $("#preview"), 
      preview = $preview[0];

  preview.width  = $preview.width();
  preview.height = $preview.height();
});
```

Comment: Thank you :). I have done as you suggested and updated the HTML at the link, but there is still a noticeable quality drop.